# firebase firestore how to create nested collection based on recent created document Id?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

I am inserting data into a new collection. Once insertion is done I want to get the `id` of that document and create another collection based on that `id`. I've tried with my code but it did not work.
here is my code :

```js
const insertData = async() => {
  const geocollection = GeoFirestore.collection('home');
  try {
    await geocollection.add({
      title: title,
      timestamps: firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      name: name,
      coordinates: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(lat, long),
      images: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(...downloadUrls),
      user: user,
      status: 0,
    }).then(async(e) => {
      idx = e.id;
      await geocollection.doc(idx)
        .set({
          menu1title: menu1title,
          price1: price1,
          image1: image1,
          menu2title: menu2title,
        });
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

Edited :

that's how I've resolved that issue , I have replaced

```
await geocollection.doc(idx)
        .set({ ...
```

by

```
const db = firestore()
   await db.collection("home").doc(idx).collection('menu').doc()
                      .set({ ....})
```

Comment: Where do you intend to create this new collection? Do you want it to be a subcollection of the newly created document?

If so, you could try the example at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query

Comment: thanks @BobHogg for your help , but  I have followed the link and its examples but did not succed

Comment: What about your code above, or the examples I linked to, does not work? Do you get an error message and if so, what is it? Or does it do something, just not what you intended to happen?

Comment: thanks @BobHogg link helped me to figure out to get this done thank you